# Scraping <span id> with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I'm a noob to web scraping and Ruby.

I'm using rails and I'm trying to scrape the last price at the top of the page of `vaultofsatoshi.com`. I came across this tutorial at: `http://hunterpowers.com/data-scraping-and-more-with-ruby-nokogiri-sinatra-and-heroku/` however I'm unsure how to adapt it to this scenario. I want to retrieve the price here: `<span id="ticker-last-price">716.68571<span class="trailing-zeroes">000</span></span>`. It seems like I can just use the unique value of  to get the value but I don't know how to implement this exactly.

To clarify, I do not need the trailing zeroes and the website is at `https://www.vaultofsatoshi.com/`

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give me the webpage link.. so that I can try ?

Comment: You only want `716.68571` or all the trailing zeros too ?

Comment: Clarified the question...links is vaultofsatoshi.com and I do not need the trailing zeroes. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Tried `doc.css("#ticker-last-price")` and I could see only zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Although my previous attempt didn't work, here is a way to do it. Just call the API with relevant parameters.  I still couldn't figure out why I cant get the value I see on the screen :-).

```
...
require 'json'
...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.vaultofsatoshi.com/ticker_data.php? \
         order_currency=BTC&payment_currency=CAD"))

doc = JSON.parse(doc)  #=> {..., "max_price"=>"721.00000000"...}
doc["max_price"]       #=> "721.00000000"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will have to be the compromise. I don't understand why the API does not have the "last price"...only "max price" and others. Thanks nonetheless!